# right, left and position relative ancestor issue

Tags: html, css, position

Let's say you have something like this:

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
     <div id="third">
        <div id="zeone"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

#first, #second, #third {
  position: relative;
}
#first {
  different from others height, width etc
}
#second {
  different from others height, width etc
}
#third {
  different from others height, width etc
}
```

Normally if I want to set my `zeone` div to `position: relative` and give it `right: value;` or/and `left: value;` it will be relative to the positioned ancestor - the div third. Is there a way to make it relative to div first or second? If so, how can I achieve this, please?

Comment: "Now, normally if I want to set my zeone div to position: relative " => You mean `position: absolute` ?

Comment: No, I meant `position: relative;`

Comment: only by unsetting position:relative to static for  #third, OR by calculating manually/js the offset of Zeone against the #second div

Comment: Well yeah, but that's why I'm asking this question here... perhaps there's some trick or something we can use

Comment: Setting `position: relative` doesn't set it relative to the parent. It sets it relative to its static position. You can set it relative to its parent by setting the parent to an absolute position. Not the same thing!

Comment: Bram Vanroy, well whatever dude... you got the idea of the problem, didn't you? If you'll use `left` or/and `right` it will be relative to the ancestor... that's the problem here.

Comment: @tusoyo you're wrong, when an element is relative positioned, left, top, bottom and right moves the element relative to its initial position. Look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=relative

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you want to absolutely position a div within a div, but let me show you both `absolute` within `relative` & all `relative` div.

**Relative parent, absolute child.**

Just make the parent `position:relative` and child `position:absolute`.
For example:

```css
#first {
  position: relative;
  background-color:#C555CC;
  width:500px;
}
#second {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#CCC555;
  right:0;
  width:400px;
}
#third{
  background-color:#C555CC;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  }

#zeone{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  right:0;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  }
```

```html
<div id="first">First
  <div id="second">Second<br />
    This is absolute positioned.
     <div id="third">Third
        <div id="zeone">Inner-most<br />This is absolute positioned.</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you just meant all relative,

**Relative parent, relative child.**

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
}
#first {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #755D21;
}
#second {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
#third {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
#zeone {
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">First
  <div id="second">Second
    <br />This is absolute positioned.
    <div id="third">Third
      <div id="zeone">Inner-most
        <br />This is absolute positioned.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And that's why I'm positioning three divs to relative?  No, bud. I want to position them all relative, but the last one, just as an example, I want to position with left and right relative to previously relative div and not for it's ancestor

Comment: @tusoyo check my examples.

Comment: Ani Menon, now do the trick and make `third` div `position:relative`. COME ON, dude...

Comment: @tusoyo is that what you wanted?

Comment: No hard feelings Ani, but wtf?! :D this is actually THE PROBLEM, man... how on earth do you think THIS solving the problem with `left` and `right`?

Comment: @tusoyo what is wrong? I am not getting you. What did you want?

Comment: I wanted the `left` and `right` of the `zeone` will be relative to div `first` or `second`

Comment: ok. Now second div is `left:50px`, third is `right:50px` and the innermost one `left:50px;`. @tusoyo that cleared your doubt?

Comment: OMG dude :) It's nice you're trying to help etc, but man... this is not helping at all :) the `left-right` of `zeone` is still being relative to `third` :D It's kinda cute tho you're trying to manipulate them like this :D

Comment: What exactly do you want? Put up a pic of the desired output. I have tried my best, your explanation is not helping.